# Count a row and showing it in a td

Tags: php, sql

I need to count number of name in a table like this:

```
<td>
<?php 
$count_name="SELECT count(name) AS Total FROM users WHERE name=".$rows['name'];
$count_res=mysqli_query($con, $count_name);
$count = mysqli_fetch_array($count_res);
print_r($count);
?>
</td>
```

Where $rows['name'] is a result of another working query. I tried everything but I always get errors so any help with it ?

Comment: Why don't you do a var_dump on $rows to see what's really there. Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Mysqli_query probably returns false. Like I said, check what's inside $rows. Also as mentioned you need quotes in your sql query.

Comment: show little more code before this, where your first query comes, may be helpful.

Comment: It is just an sql query where it select * and I got the name from it as $rows['name'] I tested this part and it works, now I got Array ( [0] => 1 [Total] => 1 ) but I need only to show [Total] => 1 , please continue with me in the comment below of Anik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name is `string` . you have use it inside `''`

try like this

```
name='".$rows['name']."'"
```

Full form

```
$count_name="SELECT count(name) AS Total FROM users WHERE name='".$rows['name']."'";
```

**EDIT**

> I got this: Array ( [0] => 1 [Total] => 1 ) But I need To see
>   only Total = 1 without Array([0]

Just print via column name

like this

```
echo $count["Total"];
```

Comment: Okay I got this: Array ( [0] => 1 [Total] => 1 ) But I need To see only Total = 1 without Array([0]

Comment: If I use echo $count; I got an error array to string conversion

Comment: I got this as result Array ( [0] => 1 [Total] => 1 ) But I need to show just [Total] => 1

Comment: then just access it via column name like `echo $count["Total"];` or `echo $count[0];`

Comment: It works now thanks, edit your code to make it as an answer